# send wiegand from raspberry

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to send data as wiegand in a raspberry, my idea is to make two waves with the PIGPIO library, and send with their respective data, you wrote a code in C, but it doesn't work correctly.
In my case, the array of bits that I sent simulating the high and off voltages, in the Wiegand reception from the raspberry, do not match.
I am using NodeJS for this program,
If you could help me it would be of great help.
PS: I think it's because of the issue of sending from a buffer, but I wouldn't know how to handle it anymore.

uno facilityCode y uno IdCard en 26 bit orig/invert

```
10000000100000000000000010
01000000000000000100000001
```

example:

```
send:10000000100000000000000010
```

reception:

```
[
  0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  1
]
```

example2:

```
send:01000000000000000100000001
```

reception:

```
[
  0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  1
]
```

[dejo el codigo de github ya que stack no me permite subirlo](https://github.com/alanezze/send_wiegand/blob/main/send-wiegand.js)

```
    const pigpio = require('pigpio');
const Gpio = pigpio.Gpio;
var dateNow= new Date()
var date = dateNow.getMilliseconds();

//declaro los pines y los activo
const outPin0 = 12;
const output0 = new Gpio(outPin0, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT});
output0.digitalWrite(1);

const outPin1 = 13;
const output1 = new Gpio(outPin1, {mode: Gpio.OUTPUT}); 
output1.digitalWrite(1);
pigpio.waveClear();
//creo las ondas
let firstWaveForm = [];
let secondWaveForm = [];
let envio = [];

//let wiegand26bits= [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0];
let wiegand26bits= [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

 
//wiegand green 0
let x = 0
for (wiegand26bits[x]; x < wiegand26bits.length; x++) {
  if (wiegand26bits[x]=== 0) {
    firstWaveForm.push({ gpioOn: outPin0, gpioOff: 0, usDelay: 1000});
    //firstWaveForm.push({ gpioOn: 0, gpioOff: outPin0, usDelay: 1000 });
  } else {
    firstWaveForm.push({ gpioOn: 0, gpioOff: outPin0, usDelay: 1000 });
    //firstWaveForm.push({ gpioOn: outPin0, gpioOff: 0, usDelay: 5000});
  }
}
 console.log(firstWaveForm);
 //creo las ondas para enviar
pigpio.waveAddGeneric(firstWaveForm);
let firstWaveId = pigpio.waveCreate();
 console.log(firstWaveId);
 

//wiegand white 1
let y = 0
for (wiegand26bits[y]; y < wiegand26bits.length; y++) {
  if (wiegand26bits[y]!== 0) {
    secondWaveForm.push({ gpioOn: outPin1, gpioOff: 0, usDelay: 1000});
    //secondWaveForm.push({ gpioOn: 0, gpioOff: outPin1, usDelay: 1000});
  } else {
    secondWaveForm.push({ gpioOn: 0, gpioOff: outPin1, usDelay: 1000});
    //secondWaveForm.push({ gpioOn: outPin1, gpioOff: 0, usDelay: 1000});
  }
}
 //creo las ondas para enviar
pigpio.waveAddGeneric(secondWaveForm);
console.log(secondWaveForm);
let secondWaveId = pigpio.waveCreate();
 console.log(secondWaveId);

//armo las cadenas y repito una vez
if (firstWaveId >= 0 && secondWaveId >= 0 && firstWaveForm.length == secondWaveForm.length)  {
  let chain = [firstWaveId, 255, 0,1, secondWaveId, 255, 0,1];
   pigpio.waveChain(chain);
}

//envio la cadena de onda
 while (pigpio.waveTxBusy()) {}

//elimino las ondas
pigpio.waveDelete(firstWaveId);

pigpio.waveDelete(secondWaveId);

pigpio.waveClear();
```

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should be in English.

Comment: hello , What part is not understood or not read?